# FTPS - Signaling that a file has been downloaded

Tags: java, download, ftps

I'm working on a Java-project where I need to download files via FTPS and wonder how/if there is a way to signal that the file has been downloaded at a later time, i.e. not as the actual download has completed? I guess there need to be some setting in the FTPS-protocol and some message that I need to send to inform of the completed download (instead of the actual download being the signal that the download was complete).

Thanks in advance,
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is a pretty simple synchronous filetransfer protocol and I would be very surprised if it has a feature to validate the download and confirm good reception for example.

If you can send a marker file back with a sha hash to confirm good reception or use an alternative communication the file has been sent.